# Проблема с ckeditor

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, form, javascript

Столкнулся с проблемой, использую jquery.form и ckeditor.
На странице объявлены параметры плагина

```
            $(document).ready(function() { 
    var AddFormOptions = { 
       beforeSubmit:  bef,  // pre-submit callback 
       success:       showResponse,  // post-submit callback

       // other available options: 
       url:        '',         // override for form's 'action' attribute 
       type:       'post',        // 'get' or 'post', override for form's 'method' attribute 
       dataType:   'json'        // 'xml', 'script', or 'json' (expected server response type) 
   }; 
   $('form').ajaxForm(AddFormOptions); 
});
```

При попытке отправить textarea к ктоторому прикреплен редактор при первой попытке отправляется пустое поле, и только при второй отправляется то, что в ней на самом деле есть. Если убрать выше приведенный код то все отправляется правильно с первого раза, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы все не правильно делаете. У ckeditor есть специальная API функция для получения контента загруженного в редактор. Примерно делается это так.

Реактор уже должен быть создан.

```
content = editor.getData();
```

Советую для избежания проблем отправки и сохранения данных немножко перекодировать данные.

> content = content.replace("/+/g",
> "&#43"); content =
> content.replace("/\/g", "&#92");

Отправляем данные на сервер. К примеру так.

> $.ajax({
>           type: "post",
>           url: 'index.php,
>           data: "content=" + content,
>           dataType: "html",
>           success: function(msg){
>                       //
>           } });

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateCKEditors() {
    for(var editor in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[editor].updateElement();
    }
}
```

Перед отправкой надо выполнить Ф-ю.